# AEM CQMS Why allias create an copy

Tags: duplicates, copy, nodes, aem

I have a problem with AEM CQMS
Do you know why, when I use the option "allias"; AEM double my page?

To be more specific My problem is this:

- I add an alliance on one page.
- I change the name of this page (I do
  not change anything on the allias.)

And now any changes that are made on this page are no longer repercuted on the allias page :/

The only reason that I see is my page is duplicated but why ?

Do you have a solution ?

cordially
J.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: how you have used "alias", are you using page properties Advanced tab **Alias** property. AFAIK that should not create any duplicate for the page. the alias name is used to call the page with another name under the same path.